# Is it safe to assume that $x=y$ for the equation $x^y=y^x$?

Tags: exponentiation

This thought came to me when I was thinking about exponents. Is the only solution for $x^y=y^z$ be $x=y$? How exactly would we prove there are no other numbers or how would we exactly solve this?

Comment: Well, $2^4=4^2,$ so they don't have to be equal.

Comment: All you can assume is $\frac{\ln y}y=\frac{\ln x}x$, obviously assuming $x,y\neq 0$

Comment: @3above Oh that’s true. Then what about $x^y=y^z=z^x$? Or in fact up to an infinite amount variables?